# Как в Owl carousel сменить слайд по наведению на определенный элемент на сайте?

Tags: javascript, jquery, owl-carousel

Допустим имеется самый обычный слайдер:

```
<div class="owl-carousel owl-theme" id="portfolio-hat-slider">
<div class="item"><h1>1</h1></div>
<div class="item"><h2>2</h2></div>
<div class="item"><h3>3</h3></div>
<div class="item"><h4>4</h4></div>
</div>
```

Где-то на сайте есть элемент с **id="elem"**

Чтобы при наведении на элемент "**elem**" в слайдере стал активным (перемотался до нужного) второй слайд (h2) - как такое можно закодить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('#id').mousecenter(function(){
owl.trigger('next.owl.carousel');
})
```

Перелистывание при наведение на элемент id. 
 А также есть метод перелистывания к конкретному слайду при условии что dots в настройках owl включены :

```
$('#id').mousecenter(function(){
owl.trigger('to.owl.carousel',[1,200]); // 1 это слайд к кот.нужно переместиться, speed это скорость в мс.
})
```

Type: triggerable,
Parameter: [position, speed]

Comment: Есть немного правильнее вариант из доков https://codepen.io/UnluckySerivelha/pen/ZRXrGb

Comment: @МайклМиллер я из офф источника методы посмотрел,как там лучше или правильнее не смотрел, но судя по офу, то это делается так.